# Monster footsteps (animation)

Tags: animation, sound-design, footsteps, monster

I've got a short animation I'm working on where a statue comes alive and wreaks havoc on a bunch of chickens. Lately, I'm having a bit of difficulty with its footsteps. I've been trying to use different types of boulder/rock crashing/exploding sounds as well as putting an LPF on rocket-type explosions and using fades to give them a shorter decay. Anybody have any other interesting ideas to try out/experience cutting to something like this?

Answer (score 5):

On top of the footsteps, you should think about the effect the footsteps have on their surrounding environment. This could be rattling floorboards in a chicken coop, slapback from distant hills, debris falling, anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Pitch the chickens up a bit to give the contrast effect of the footsteps sounding deeper and lower.

Answer (score 1):

How about thunder for the footsteps? I agree with Roger on the effects of the footsteps on the surrounding so perhaps some earthquake or avalanche type rumbling as well. The faster he walks, the bigger the 'earthquake' he causes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like an concert base drumb, maybe put some metallic pieces on it to give it that low rubble with a rattle. I really want to see this sequence, it sound great.

Answer (score 0):

Heres something I discovered by accident once. I was doing a sound remix for fun and I was making footsteps of a giant robot monster that destroys buildings.  Open the sound of rubbing a balloon and use that, pitch it, whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, these are all some great ideas.

@Roger had definitely thought of that, since the monster is running around a temple ruin I'm messing a lot with additional smaller rock debris sounds, although your comment sparked the idea of its entrance affecting the BGs, having birds suddenly scattering.

@Tak I'll have to try out the thunder and let you know of the results.

@Peter I've got something kind of similar going on for my "bass" layer right now, some very deep footsteps that sound a bit like gigantic de-tuned drums.

@Chris That's...interesting. I'll have to mess with that to see what you mean, but did the balloon sound emulate the sound of bending steel in the buildings or something?